# Accessing my virtual machine on local network?

Tags: laravel, localhost, server, laravel-5, homestead

I'm trying to access a homestead site over my network.

I've followed the advice [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/accessing-homesteadvagrant-site-from-different-device-on-same-network?page=1).

In my hosts file I have a variety of sites:

```
127.0.0.1 orange.app
127.0.0.1 apple.app
127.0.0.1 pear.app
127.0.0.1 banana.app

192.168.0.4 banana.app
```

I go to 192.168.0.4:8000 from a device on my network I am shown the first project alphabetically (apple.app), how can I get it so it shows banana.app?

Comment: Why don't you directly go to banana.app:8000?

Comment: If I do that I get This webpage is not available

Comment: Have you correctly set your [virtual hosts](http://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/)?

Comment: Shouldn't those point to the VM's IP (192.168.10.10) and can you please post your `Homestead.yaml` file

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map an IP address to a host. If you're looking to share your application within your network you make use of something like [vagrant share](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/share/) or [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).